# Dynamically add canvas layer to leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm looping through an array in JavaScript and want to dynamically update/redraw the leaflet canvas layer at every increment to produce an animated map? I have attempted moving the loop around which produces "map already initiated" errors, and refreshing html content but cant seem to get anywhere. The lat and long don't change only the values in the array do. Any help would be great.

**Full Code:**https://pastebin.com/CzTnGCQt

**Code:**

```
    var value = <?php echo json_encode($sensor) ?>; 
    //(24) [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 7, 6, 4, 6, 5, 4, 8, 6, 7, 2]

    var count = <?php echo json_encode($count, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>;   
    var i = 0, howManyTimes = value.length;       

    var lats = <?php echo json_encode($lat, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>;
    //(3) [-3737, -3501, -4170]

    var lons = <?php echo json_encode($long, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ?>;   
    // (3) [14083, 13875, 14709]


    var tiles = new L.tileLayer('http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/briegn1.cfc1a74d/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{attribution: "<a href='https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/' target='_blank'>&copy; Mapbox &copy; OpenStreetMap</a> <a class='mapbox-improve-map' href='https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/' target='_blank'>Improve this map</a>"});


    var leafletMap = L.map('map', {
        center: [-37.3785, 140.8365],
        zoom: 10,
    });             

    leafletMap.addLayer(tiles);           
    //Important line to make sure the tiles (more specifically the continental labels) show up on top of the grids.
    $('.leaflet-tile-pane').css('z-index',10);



                       function f() {

     console.log(value[i+1], value[i+2], value[i+3]);

      var d = [value[i+1], value[i+2], value[i+3]];
            data = d;   


            data.map(function(d,i) {
                var pixel = LatLongToPixelXY(lats[i]/100., lons[i]/100);
                vertz.push(pixel.x, pixel.y)
                var colors = Colors2Get[showVar][d];
                if (colors[0] < 1) {
                    colorz.push(colors[0]/256., colors[1]/256., colors[2]/256., 0.0);
                } else {
                    colorz.push(colors[0]/256., colors[1]/256., colors[2]/256., 1.0);
                }
            });

            numPoints = data.length;
            if (gl) {
                vertArray = new Float32Array(vertz);
                colorArray = new Float32Array(colorz);
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vertexPositionAttribute, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
                gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vertexPositionAttribute);
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexColorBuffer);
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vertexColorAttribute, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
                gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vertexColorAttribute);
                glLayer.redraw();
            }

     i += 3

    if( i < howManyTimes ){
        setTimeout( f, 4000 );


    }
}

f();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You could have a look at the Leaflet source and experiment with `map._resetView()`.

Comment: @peeebeee Thanks seems like a great place to find some help. I will have a look now.